# div not lining up correctly

Tags: html, css

I have a header where I have a background image that repeats horizontally. It has content inside it setup as ul list. I wanted to float some of them left and one of the right. I also have a div after the ul list acting as a cap for the end of my header. This cap has a rounded corner. I also have this set to float right and here lies the issue. I'm posting a dummy version for you to view. Can anyone tell me how I can have the input field holder float right and still have my cap float right without getting set below the header like it is right now.

[Link to header html](http://www.artaholic.com/html/header/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
<ul>
    <li class="live"><a href="#">button1</a></li>
    <li class="schedule"><a href="#">button2</a></li>
    <li class="dvr"><a href="#">button3</a></li>
    <li class="leftCap"></li>
    <li class="tools">
      <form class="search" action="get">
        <input class="searchField" name="q" maxlength="40">
      </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Your leftcap was outside the ul as a div, but placing it inside the ul will correct this.

Comment: Hey Joseph is there way to stop the browser from pushing the tools li down to the next line when you scale the browser to a small size.

Comment: never mind I just set the wrapper to a min-width in pixels and it did the job.